# R - how to concantenate lists by adding up all numbers in each elements if they shares same rownames

Tags: r, list, concatenation

I have a two dataframes which some rows shares the same index and some does not.

when I tried functions to add up these lists, it just copied the second list and pasted it after the first one

what I want to do is, if they shares the same rownames, then add the numbers of each columns in both rows. if they does not share, then just paste after the first one.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

---

this was too vague so I'm editing this to clarify... my bad

my question is, how to add:

```
#first dataframe  

col1 = c("apple", "beer", "golf") 

col2 = c(1, 5, 9) 

col3 = c(5, 6.3, 5.2) 

df = data.frame(col1, col2, col3)
```

and 
    #second dataframe

```
col1 = c("apple", "fire", "golf") 

col2 = c(16, 52, 19) 

col3 = c(55, 63, 9) 

df2 = data.frame(col1, col2, col3)
```

---

into a dataframe something like this?

```
col1 = c("apple", "beer", "golf", "fire") #order doesn't matter

col2 = c(17, 5, 28, 52) 

col3 = c(60, 6.3, 14.2, 63) 

output_wanted = data.frame(col1, col2, col3)
```

is there any function to perform a merge like this?

thanks...!

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example along with expected output so that it is easier to help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on the OP's update, an option is to bind the rows and then do a group by `sum` of all the other columns

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df, df2) %>%
    group_by(col1) %>% 
    summarise_all(sum)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  col1   col2  col3
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 apple    17  60  
#2 beer      5   6.3
#3 fire     52  63  
#4 golf     28  14.2
```

---

In `base R`, this can be done with `rbind` and `aggregate`

```
aggregate(.~ col1, rbind(df, df2), sum)
```

Comment: thank you for the generous help.. this solved my problem!